# Android Action bar only showing in overflow

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar, icons

In my android app .. I am trying t put a search edittext with seARCH icon .. but I cant see the search icon in action bar rather the title is seeing in overflow. I am giving my code below

activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
          android:title="@string/action_search"
          android:showAsAction="always"/>
  <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="Settings"/>

</menu>
```

MainActvity

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity 

{

     WebView wv1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        wv1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wView1);
        wv1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv1.loadUrl("http://www.example.com/songs/");




    }

     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main_actions, menu);

            return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

<del>I think you must return `true` instead of 

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu) 

in `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` method</del>

Excuses. That was wrong.

I think this problem has something to do with the base class you are using. Your are subclassing ActionBarActivity instead of Activity. This means that you are using compatibility for previous versions. For this to work, you need to set your application's Theme to Theme.AppCompat (or a similar one), and also include the Support Library. Look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html)

Comment: No the same problem.. i gave return true;

Comment: But, did you remove the call to super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)? I think it creates an empty menu. If you call this after inflating yours, it will be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

Use Search Manager n search view in onCreateOptionsMenu

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main_actions, menu);

    // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)
            .getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
            .getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

and in your main.xml add this item for search

```
   <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
      android:title="@string/action_search"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
      android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"/>
```

Comment: Nothing ... only white screen is coming

Comment: What is your target device ?

Comment: minsdk = 8 and maxsdk = 19

Answer (score 0):

I just realized how to fix the problem!

your menu xml file should have an starting tag like:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:myApp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
```

you can replace

> myApp

with any names you want, NOW the important part is when you define an action item:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/actionitem_switch_view"
    android:title="@string/view_as"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    myApp:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_view_as_list"/>
```

You'd have two showAsAction tags,one for API<11 devices and one for the others,
**Look closely** that the two showAsAction tags are different,one is from Android namespace and the other's from the tag you defined in menu Starting point